# Peer react-dom@15.6.2 wants react@^15.6.2

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I'm trying to upgrade from React 0.14.9 to React 15.6.2, but am running into a dependency issue.

> npm ERR! peerinvalid The package react@15.6.2 does not satisfy its
>   siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
>
> npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-dom@15.6.2 wants react@^15.6.2

I don't understand this error, because it seems to indicate that I need react 15.6.2 for react-dom 15.6.2, but react 15.6.2 is what is installed.

In my package.json, I've tried various combinations, with and without the ^, but the same error persists:

```
"react": "15.6.2",
"react-dom": "15.6.2",
```

Comment: Have you tried a fresh install? `npm ci`

Comment: I'm on npm 2.15.8, so `npm ci` isn't available. I have tried a fresh install by running:

`rm -rf node_modules`
`npm cache clean`
`npm install`

Comment: Alright. And that didn't work? It seems that [it might be npm v2 that is the problem](https://github.com/auth0/lock/issues/1126). Have you tried upgrading?

Comment: Thanks @Tholle. I upgraded my version of npm and that did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is an issue with npm v2](https://github.com/auth0/lock/issues/1126). It will be resolved if you upgrade it.